# Getting error when trying to create Availability Test

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureportal

I'm trying to create an Availability Test in Application Insights as seen in this guide;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability

But creating a test fails. I asked my colleague to try creating one aswell (On a different account and different directory) and he gets the same error.

This is on Europe North.

The error:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-unauthorized

I cannot create a classic nor a standard test, i've tried enabling/disabling all possible options.

If anyone would like to test aswell, or have a solution to this, that would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an outage in Application Insights management operation plane (including creation of Availability tests): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor-status/experiencing-data-access-issue-in-azure-portal-for-many-data/ba-p/2981759

Root Cause: The failure was due to one of the backend service became unhealthy.
Incident Timeline: 4 Hours - 11/18, 14:00 UTC through 11/18, 18:00 UTC